# Can i separate the selection model from an NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, selection, nstableview

Is there any way how i can maintain my own data model of selected items in a NSTableView.
I find it either pretty slow or complicated to keep the state of selected items when i update the table model.

Comment: Are you saying that when the table reloads you want the same *objects* to be selected afterwards, rather than the same *rows*?

Comment: Yes. This is what i would expect in most cases because the user thinks in items and not index numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain your own NSMutableIndexSet for the selected row indexes. If you're binding the table view's columns to an array controller's `arrangedObjects` and the array controller's `contentArray` to an array you own, bind the array controller's `selectedIndexes` to your index set. If you're implementing a data source, be the view's delegate as well and implement the delegate methods relevant to managing the selection.